# imap_search text or body criteria not working

Tags: php, imap

I've noticed that "text" or "body" criteria is not working on every mail server. Ex: `UNDELETED TEXT "hello"`
Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Not every server supports IMAP to spec - if your search works on one server and not on another, then it is possible that it is a server bug.